# Understanding Javascript Object and Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to fix a Wordpress plugin that is no longer supported. I have narrowed down the error. The following line is the problem:

i[C][0];

It is returning undefined in the function below:

```
`function S(i) {
        var C,
            P = i.length,
            E = [];
            
      for (C = 0; C < P; C++) {
      console.log(i[C]);
      console.log( JSON.stringify(i[C], null, 2) ); 
      E[C] = i[C][0].offsetTop;
      }
        return E;
    }`
```

I logged i[C] and have the following result:

[image: From Console]

"length": 0,
"prevObject": {
"0": {},
"length": 1,
"prevObject": {
"0": {},
"1": {},
"2": {},
"3": {},
"4": {},
"5": {
"jQuery351075030630793491351": {
"display": ""
}
},
"length": 6,
"prevObject": {
"0": {},
"length": 1,
"prevObject": {
"0": {},
"length": 1,
"prevObject": {
"0": {},
"length": 1
}
}
}
}
}
}

Here is a link to the page:
https://wolseleyfamilyplace.com/events/

Another note, P is equal to 5.

I am not that familiar with Javascript and reading the objects. Why is the i[C][0] returning undefined? Can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was expecting `i` to be a jQuery object... And now what is passed to the function is a DOM element.

Try to just remove `[0]` from `E[C] = i[C][0].offsetTop;` It all works fine, that was it!

---

To just be fullproof... In case both DOM and jQuery object can be passed to the function, you could do:

`E[C] = i[C][0] ? i[C][0].offsetTop : i[C].offsetTop`
                      jQuery--^                    DOM--^